# vba print pdf files for specific list of sheets

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, printing

Is it possible to modify this code to print a few pdf files for a specific list of sheets?

```
    Sub printselection()
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim wks As Worksheet
        Dim arr() As String
        Dim i As Long: i = 0
        Dim x As Integer

        For x = 1 To 3
        For Each rng In Sheets("Consolidated").Range(Cells(x, x), Cells(x, x))

            If Trim(rng.Value) <> "" Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Set wks = Nothing
                Set wks = Sheets(rng.Value)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If wks Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox "Sheet " & rng.Value & " does not exist"
                Else
                    ReDim Preserve arr(i)
                    arr(i) = wks.Name
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next rng
        Dim printSheets As Variant
        printSheets = arr
        Worksheets(printSheets).PrintOut Preview:=False, ActivePrinter:="Adobe PDF", PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:=PSFileName
    Next x

 End Sub
```

I am learning as I go with vba.....it works for just column A and gets hung up on the last line and was hoping it would ask for a file name as it moves to the next column X.  Here is a sample of column sheet names ( I want to print each column of sheet names to a different pdf file)

```
       A                    B                   C
CA 10 - 50 Area 1   CO 10 - 50 Area 1   GA 10 - 50 Area 1
CA 10 - 50 Area 2   CO 10 - 50 Area 2   GA 10 - 50 Area 2
CA 10 - 50 Area 3   CO 10 - 50 Area 3   GA 10 - 50 Area 3
CA 10 - 50 Area 4       
CA 10 - 50 Area 5
```

(column A is CA, column B is CO and column C is GA)

Comment: Run a loop to array `printSheets` and run print command for each sheet in `printSheets` array.

Comment: Thank you.  I am not sure exactly the syntax for that. I tried changing printSheets = arr to printSheets = arr(x) but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop for each sheet in your `printSheets` array:

```
For Each itm In printSheets
Worksheets(itm).PrintOut Preview:=False, ActivePrinter:="Adobe PDF", PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:=PSFileName

Next itm
```

Comment: Thank you.  I modified the code a bit and this works without error.  This almost works the way I want.  I need help with 2 or 3 more changes. 1. It does ask me to save 3 files which is what I want but after x=1, I want to clear the array before moving to x=2.  How do I clear the "cache" for the array after saving the file to pdf? 2. Is there a simple way to change to code from saving to pdf to an excel file instead? 3. (this would be more nice to have) Automate naming of the files using a column/list of file names in a specific column in excel?

Comment: For x = 1 To 3
    For Each rng In Sheets("Groups").Range(Cells(5, x), Cells(8, x))
          Set wks = Sheets(rng.Value)
           ReDim Preserve arr(i)
                arr(i) = wks.Name
                i = i + 1            
    Next rng
    Dim printSheets As Variant
    printSheets = arr
    Worksheets(printSheets).PrintOut Preview:=False, ActivePrinter:="Adobe PDF", PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:=PSFileName
Next x