# VBA Excel export specified range of sheets to PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I have a few sheets located at the end, which I don't want to include in my PDF print.

My code works but looks quite tough...

```
 Sub DPPtoPDF()

 Sheets("Readme").Visible = False
 Sheets("Asbuilt Photos 1").Visible = False
 Sheets("Asbuilt Photos 2").Visible = False
 Sheets("Splicing Photos").Visible = False
 Sheets("Sign Off Sheet").Visible = False
 Sheets("OTDR TRACE-1").Visible = False

 ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

 Sheets("Readme").Visible = True
 Sheets("Asbuilt Photos 1").Visible = True
 Sheets("Asbuilt Photos 2").Visible = True
 Sheets("Splicing Photos").Visible = True
 Sheets("Sign Off Sheet").Visible = True
 Sheets("OTDR TRACE-1").Visible = True
 Sheets("Frontsheet").Select


 End Sub
```

Basically I want to define some range of sheets, which I want to include in my PDF print.

Unfortunately, according to the thread below:

[Specify an Excel range across sheets in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923028/specify-an-excel-range-across-sheets-in-vba)

it looks like I can set the range within one sheet only.

Other approaches:

[vba print pdf files for specific list of sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236671/vba-print-pdf-files-for-specific-list-of-sheets)

[Excel VBA Macro to save series of worksheets to one pdf then repeat for different series of worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259932/excel-vba-macro-to-save-series-of-worksheets-to-one-pdf-then-repeat-for-differen)

don't work in my case

[image]

Is there any smarter option to select some range of sheets /or exclude some sheets/ for PDF printing?

Comment: Create a list of worksheets and a list of their associated ranges (if they are not all the same). Loop through the lists and copy the ranges appropriately to another (new) worksheet and export it to `PDF`. You have specified a list of worksheets not to include. Now do so with the worksheets and their associated ranges, or with one range address, , if it's always the same, and elaborate on the matters of headers, cell formatting, empty rows,... etc.

Comment: How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Add a temporary sheet to hold all the ranges you want to print.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DPPtoPDF()

    'Define ranges to print out
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsPDF As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngPDF As Range
    Dim n As Long, i As Integer
   
    ' define ranges
    Dim rngToPrint(2) As Range
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set rngToPrint(1) = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E5")
    Set rngToPrint(2) = wb.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3:F200")

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ' create sheet to hold ranges
    Set wsPDF = wb.Sheets.Add
    wsPDF.Name = "PDF Output"
    Set rngPDF = wsPDF.Range("A1")
  
    ' copy range to temporary sheet
    For i = 1 To UBound(rngToPrint)
        n = rngToPrint(i).Rows.Count
        rngToPrint(i).Copy rngPDF
        Set rngPDF = rngPDF.Offset(n + 1)
    Next

    ' print to PDF
    wsPDF.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
      ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name, _
      Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
      IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

    ' delete temporary sheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsPDF.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 End Sub
```